# LUA string, drop non alphanumeric or space

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, gsub, lua-patterns

I have customer input that may include letters, digits or spaces.  For instance:

```
local customer_input = 'I need 2 tomatoes';
```

or

```
local customer_input = 'I need two tomatoes';
```

However, due to the nature of my application, I may get #, *, @, etc, in the customer_input string. I want to remove any non alphanumeric characters but the space.

I tried with these:

```
customer_input , _ = customer_input:gsub("%W%S+", "");
```

This one drops everything but the first word in the phrase.

or

```
customer_input , _ = customer_input:gsub("%W%S", "");
```

This one actually drops the space and the first letter of each word.

So, I know I am doing it wrong but I am not really sure how to match alphanumeric + space. I am sure this must be simple but I have not been able to figure it out.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
customer_input , _ = customer_input:gsub("[^%w%s]+", "");
```

See the [Lua demo online](https://ideone.com/tWtjBE)

**Pattern details**

- `[^` - start of a negated character class that matches any char but:

  - `%w` - an alphanumeric
  - `%s` - a whitespace
- `]+` - 1 or more times.

Comment: Hi @Wiktor, thanks very much! It works like a charm.  I completely forgot the [...] to negate an expression.